# Can I use compiz wallpapers and still show my icons?

Tags: compiz, icons, desktop-background

Wondering if there is a way to have my multiple wallpapers through compiz and have icons.

When you use wallpapers for compiz it hides the icons. Is there a way I can get them to show up?

Answer (score 0):

Just install Ubuntu Tweak tool : http://ubuntu-tweak.com/downloads/ , After install u can customize ur desktop, like show or not ur icon, customize ur Unity or whatever. For customize ur compiz pls install ccsm, in terminal : sudo apt-get install ccsm . Go to the dash, and customize ur compiz with ccsm.

Comment: no. that only turns the icons back on. which then makes the multiple wallpapers go away. i want both wallpapers and icons on my 4 desktops.